Custom pagination Index issue in REACT
In react, I make custom Pagination, but ISSUE is when the page changed using next or Prev button the INDEXING restart from "0", I want when I click on next it start from last index
example if I have an [array] for "99" and I map all the elements and "20" elements per page a but the issue is every time I click on next button the index is start from "1 to 20" and then I click on next I again start from "1", I want when I click on next it starts from "21 to 40"
every time NEXT or PREV button clicked the 20 *element *save in products array
{products ? (
          products.map((item, index) => {
            // const i = useMemo(() => index + 1, [index]);
            return (
              <tr
                key={index}>
                <td>{index++}</td>
</tr>


Could you please provide the complete code which includes the "next" part?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

To update value of index or any other value use useState or useRef hook.
